# How are float results rounded to integer ones when converting from float to int?

Tags: c, type-conversion

How are float results rounded to integer ones when converting from float to int?

Sometimes I made some complex arithmetic operation (which comprises multiplications, divisions etc) between integer variables and convert the result again to int.

Example:

```
result = (int) ((int1 + int2) * int3 / int4);
```

It happens that sometimes the result is rounded to the nearest integer, other times to the lower integer even if the float result is nearer to the upper one, sometimes instead the result is rounded by 2 integer numbers up or down (i.e. if the result is -150.69 it can happen that result = -149).

There is some law in conversions from float to int or it depends on the case?

Thanks in advance.

---

Example:

```
int1 = 31;
int2 = -1366;
int3 = 50;
int4 = 1000;
```

result should be -66.75 but the returned one is -65.

Comment: Please give an example (set of inputs `int1` ... `int4`) that exhibit the behavior you're describing.

Comment: Are all the `intn` variables ints? If so, then there is are no floats here, and I suppose that your question is really "How is integer division performed".

Comment: @interjay yes all the variables are integer.

Comment: Are you sure that this comes out to -65 and not -66?  If so, what are the actual types (unsigned int, short int, just int, etc) and which compiler are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, unless `int1` through `int4` are actually floats, you don't have any floating point types, so your question is irrelevant to your code.

As for the question itself, floating point to integer conversion always takes place by truncation (discarding the fractional portion). For rounding, the standard library has a number of functions like `floor`, `ceil`, `round`, etc. that can perform different types of rounding.

Comment: so if my 4 variables are all integer each operation is truncated? Is this the reason why it can happen that -150.69 is "rounded" to -149?

Comment: @aliants: Yes, each operation with integer operands is done individually with integer arithmetic. Each intermediate result is truncated (or overflows) to match the type being used. More than that, C has particular rules for which integer types are used. Generally, if you use `int` objects, you will have `int` arithmetic, and results that overflow what an `int` can have will cause problems. If you use one `unsigned int` object, the other `int` operand in most binary operators will be converted to `unsigned int`. If you use a `long` with an `int`, the `int` will be converted to `long`, etc.

Comment: Note that this still doesn't explain why -66.75 is "rounded" to -65 (instead of truncated to -66 as would be expected).  In your example (here in the comment) -150.69 would be truncated to -150, NOT "rounded" to -149.